# javaFX MediaPlayer getCurrentTime() unreliable

Tags: java, media-player, javafx

To play a mp3 file, I am using the `javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer` class.
But I noticed that the currentTimeProperty is not reliable after using the `seek()` method.

The method `initMediaPlayer()` in the code below is called when the user has choosen a mp3 file. The playback time is shown in a time slider (`=timeSlider`) which the user can move to start the playback from any point in the song. The current position in the song is also displayed in a label (`=timeLabel`).

When I start the playback with `play()`, and when I pause or restart the song with `pause()` or `stop()`, everything works fine.

The problem is that after using `seek()` the `currentTimeProperty` is not longer correct.
This is becomes very noticeable towards the end of the song, then the `currentTimeProperty` is sometimes up to 4 seconds longer than the total time of the song.

What is the cause of this problem and is there a way to work around it?

```java
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        audio = new Media(audioFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
        audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindowController.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    audioPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
            Duration time = audioPlayer.getCurrentTime();
            Duration total = audioPlayer.getTotalDuration();

            if (!timeSlider.isValueChanging() &&
                total.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO)){

                timeSlider.setValue(time.toMillis() / total.toMillis() * 100);
            }

            timeLabel.setText(formatTime(time,total));
        }
    });

    timeSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
            audioPlayer.seek(audioPlayer.getTotalDuration()
                .multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / 100.0));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which depicts your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You want `ChangeListener<Duration>`, not `InvalidationListener`.

```
audioPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldDuration, newDuration) -> {
     System.out.println("Player:" + observableValue + " | Changed from playing at: " + oldDuration + " to play at " + newDuration);
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a bit more detail to your answer?

Comment: @NT3RP I added an example piece of code. He's just adding the wrong listener. I'm not sure which follow up questions there could be. :)